# copy data from app service to azure fileshare

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-web-app-service, azure-aks

i have an app service in production and I'm switching to aks so i will be using fileshare as a volume.

How to to make a copy of a folder in my app service (exp path: /home/site/wwwroot/public) to my new azure fileshare

found the azcopy command but nothing clear about the app service part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are running a Linux App Service on Azure from

> (exp path: /home/site/wwwroot/public)

To [Web SSH to your Linux App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-linux-open-ssh-session), paste the following URL into your browser and replace  with your app name:

```
https://<app-name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/webssh/host
```

[For a windows container based App Service go to the [Console](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2018/connect/azure-7-tips-and-tricks-for-azure-app-service#working-with-files-in-azure-app-service)]

Once in SSH session (or Console), please create a new fresh directory where you can mount Azure File Storage (review the [Linux App Service Limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-connect-to-azure-storage?pivots=container-linux&tabs=cli#limitations) and [Windows App Service Limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-connect-to-azure-storage?pivots=container-windows&tabs=cli#limitations)) using:

```
mkdir <mount-path-directory>
```

Use the [az webapp config storage-account add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/config/storage-account#az_webapp_config_storage_account_add) command. For example:

```
az webapp config storage-account add --resource-group <group-name> --name <app-name> --custom-id <custom-id> --storage-type AzureFiles --share-name <share-name> --account-name <storage-account-name> --access-key "<access-key>" --mount-path <mount-path-directory>
```

- `--storage-type` should be `AzureFiles`
- `--mount-path` is the directory inside the Linux container to mount to Azure Storage. Do not use / (the root directory).

Verify your storage is mounted by running the following command:

```
az webapp config storage-account list --resource-group <resource-group> --name <app-name>
```

[ **Important:** The directory specified in `--mount-path` in the container should be empty. Any content stored in this directory is deleted when the Azure Storage is mounted (if you specify a directory under `/home`, for example). If you are migrating files for an existing app, make a backup of the app and its content before you begin.]

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-connect-to-azure-storage?tabs=cli&pivots=container-linux)

Now from the SSH session (or Console) to the App Service, copy the desired source directory to the desired destination on the Azure File Storage mount using:

```
cp -r /source/directory /destination/directory/
```

**Note:** You can also create subdirectories in the mount path using `mkdir` and copy data to those subdirectories depending on your needs.

At this point, you can [mount the Azure FileShare as a Persistent Volume or Inline volume](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-files-volume) in your AKS cluster.

Comment: what is the "--custom-id <custom-id>" in the command that adds the fileshare to the webapp

Comment: The `--custom-id` parameter defines the "Name of the share configured within the web app". You can provide a name that you think best suits for your understanding. For more information on the parameters for the `az webapp config storage-account add` command please refer to the in-answer link with the command name or [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/config/storage-account?view=azure-cli-latest#az_webapp_config_storage_account_add).